# Does it matter which jack I plug into on an unpowered loudspeaker?

Tags: speakers

At work we use unpowered loudspeakers wired in parallel. I have googled a stock image. Ours are cheap, made of wood with felt on top of them.

[image]

The backs look like this.

[image]

Normally I just plug the 1/4" connector into the sockets randomly.

Does which socket I plug into matter? Is there some kind of input to output flow, such as left to right or right to left?

Answer (score 6):

The connectors are simply there to allow you to daisy chain speakers.  You can go in one and out the other.  The order does not matter at all as it is just a basic parallel circuit with the drivers in the middle.

Answer (score -1):

In a nutshell: no, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi there. This doesn't actually add anything as it was already said in the existing answer. Please read the existing posts first before posting. Thanks.